# Can I run VWD 2010 Express Project in IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, iis

Well I have developed a small project in VWD 2010 express and I want to deploy it on my windows 2003 sp2 and then I want to let the network users use it. For that I am trying to create a virtual directory in IIS 6.0.

Can I configure this web application through IIS 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, projects in VWD 2010 Express can be run on Windows 2003 Server/IIS6. Just be sure you have the correct Framework version installed on the server.